# how to score precision, recall and f1-score in a multi-class dataset using cross-validate?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

This code is working for the dataset which has 2 classes, but not in multi-class

```
scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
       'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score),
       'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score), 
       'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score)}
scores = cross_val_score(gnb,x,y, cv=5, scoring=scoring)
print(scores)
```

the error show

```
ValueError: For evaluating multiple scores, use sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate instead. {'accuracy': make_scorer(accuracy_score), 'precision': make_scorer(precision_score, average=None), 'recall': make_scorer(recall_score), 'f1_score': make_scorer(f1_score)} was passed
```

when I check the code with changed it like this

```
scores = cross_val_score(gnb,x,y, cv=5, scoring='precision')
```

the error show

```
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].
```

it's not working when I set the `average` in `make_scorer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scoring function '`f1_macro`' or '`f1_micro`' for f1. 
Likewise, '`recall_macro`' or '`recall_micro`' for recall.

When calculating precision or recall, it is important to define positive class, but in multi-class dataset, it is hard to define it.

So, average of precision (recall) per each class value (i.e., iterating each value and regard it as positive class) should be calculated.

**Edit.**

Try use the following code (micro average precision, recall, f1).

```
scoring = {'accuracy' : make_scorer(accuracy_score), 
       'precision' : make_scorer(precision_score, average = 'micro'),
       'recall' : make_scorer(recall_score, average = 'micro'), 
       'f1_score' : make_scorer(f1_score, average = 'micro')}
```

Comment: thank you, but the name 'f1_macro' is not defined, etc..

can you link me on how to define the scoring function?

Comment: I added a code, and refer it. Refer the sklearn.metrics.make_score from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html.

Comment: I have tried that way... still not working

the error still show
Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting, one of [None, 'micro', 'macro', 'weighted'].

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/kambingbersayaphitam/canny-humoment-nbc/

this is my kernel..

Comment: accuracy = cross_val_score(gnb,x,y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')
precision = cross_val_score(gnb,x,y, cv=5, scoring='precision_macro')
recall = cross_val_score(gnb,x,y, cv=5, scoring='recall_macro')
f1 = cross_val_score(gnb,x,y, cv=5, scoring='f1_macro')
print(accuracy)
print(precision)
print(recall)
print(f1)

this code is working.. :D